# Reactjs. Counter of renders

Tags: reactjs

How to make counter of renders the child component in parent?

I have 2 components `Widget` (parent) and `Message`(child). I passed counter from child to parent and trying to set getting value from child set to state. And I getting err: `Maximum update depth exceeded.`

There is **child** component `Message`:

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Message extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.changeColor = this.changeColor.bind(this);
    this.changeCount = this.changeCount.bind(this);

    this.state = { h: 0, counter: 0 };
  }

  changeColor = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      h: Math.random()
    }));
  };

  changeCount = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      counter: ++state.counter
    }));
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    this.props.getColor(this.color);
    this.changeCount();
    this.props.getCount(this.state.counter);
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    const { s, l, a } = this.props.color;

    this.color = `hsla(${this.state.h}, ${s}%, ${l}%, ${a})`;

    return (
      <p
        className="Message"
        onClick={this.changeColor}
        style={{ color: this.color }}
      >
        {children}
      </p>
    );
  }
}
```

There is **parent** component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Message from "./Message/Message";

export default class Widget extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      color: {
        s: 30,
        l: 60,
        a: 1
      },
      counter: 0
    };
  }

  getCount = count => this.setState(state => ({
    counter: state.counter
  }));

  getColor = color => {
    console.log(`the color is ${color}`);
  };

  render() {
    const counter = this.state.counter;

    return (
      <div>
        <Message
          getColor={this.getColor}
          getCount={this.getCount}
          color={this.state.color}
        >
          {undefined || `Hello World!`}
        </Message>
        {counter}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: looking at you child component, in componentDidUpdate you are again calling setstate in changeCount which in turn will trigger componentDidUpdate. 
its non ending....

Comment: what you should do is, don't keep the counter variable in state, instead keep it in (this). and increment it inside render function.

Comment: do the same thing in parent also. Don't set state in getCount. set the variable this.counter in getCount function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
export default class Message extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        this.counter = 0;
    }

    render() {
        this.counter++;
        ........
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, now child pass to parent count, but i have now same problem in parent component (infinity loop). I think is `setState` in `getCount` function. How can i fix this?

Comment: how to do it in function component?

Answer (score 38):

The answer by @Yossi counts total renders of all component instances. This solution counts how many renderes and re-renders an individual component has done.

### For counting component instance renders

```
import { useRef } from "react";


export const Counter = props => {
    const renderCounter  = useRef(0);
    renderCounter.current = renderCounter.current + 1;
    return <h1>Renders: {renderCounter.current}, {props.message}</h1>;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to count the number of renders, I am adding a static variable to all my components, and incrementing it within render().

#### For Class components:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
let renderCount = 0;

export class SampleClass extends Component {
  render() {
    if (__DEV__) {
      renderCount += 1;
      console.log(`${this.constructor.name}. renderCount: `, renderCount);
    }
    return (
        <View>
          <Text>bla</Text>
        </View>
    )
  }
}
```

#### For functional Components:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
let renderCount = 0;

export function SampleFunctional() {
  if (__DEV__) {
    renderCount += 1;
    console.log(`${SampleFunctional.name}. renderCount: `, renderCount);
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>bla</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Storing the `renderCount` outside of the component is the only simple way I can think of that doesn't generate an infinite re-renders loop. Another possibility would be to track each re-render by providing additional props such as a triggerId and avoid infinite loops, but that's getting quite complicated and (fatal) error-prone.

Comment: useRef should not cause infinite rerenders

Answer (score 1):

You can simple use `console.count('count')` inside your component, it will print the count for the amount of renders like this:

count: 1 
count: 2 
count: 3 
. 
. 
.

Answer (score 0):

The `componentDidUpdate` is calling `this.changeCount()` which calls `this.setState()` **everytime** after the component updated, which ofcourse runs infinitely and throws the error.

```
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    this.props.getColor(this.color);
    // Add a if-clause here if you really want to call `this.changeCount()` here
    // For example: (I used Lodash here to compare, you might need to import it)
    if (!_.isEqual(prevProps.color, this.props.color) {
        this.changeCount();
    }
    this.props.getCount(this.state.counter);
  }
```